# How can I persist ExtJS datagrid column hiding/showing/moving/resizing?

Tags: javascript, events, datagrid, extjs, grid

I would like to make a user's changes to an ExtJS datagrid's column display (hiding, showing, moving, resizing) persistent and stored on the server. There are a lot of events to listen to, but registering handlers on the grid itself doesn't seem to result in alerts being called:

```
    grid.on('hide', function(event)
        {
        alert('Save column order: column hidden.');
        });
    grid.on('move', function(event)
        {
        alert('Save column order: column moved.');
        });
    grid.on('resize', function(event)
        {
        alert('Save column sizes: column resized.');
        });
    grid.on('show', function(event)
        {
        alert('Save colum order: column shown.');
        });
```

(My basic approach may or may not be optimal.)

What concretely should I do to be listening in on these events? I can hide, show, move, and resize columns without triggering an alert.

Comment: This worked with a GridPanel, but an EditorGridPanel is having trouble. Any suggestions for a stateful EditorGridPanel?

Comment: Never mind the last question; I needed to set stateId and then everything was happy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**First**, you need to configure a [state provider](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.state.Provider).
[CookieProvider](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.state.CookieProvider) is the only one that comes built in with ExtJS

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
```

**Second**, mark `yourGridPanel.stateful` as `true`

**Third**, look at whether you need to change the default for [GridPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel).**stateEvents**
This is basically "*An array of events that, when fired, should trigger this component to save its state*"

**Fourth**, HttpStateProvider does not come built in with ExtJS but [Saki](http://extjs.eu/) has a [ux (user extension) for it](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?24970-Buffering-Http-State-Provider).

**Fifth**, if you want to save states of multiple components they should have either `id`  or `stateId` explicitly set.

A good approach would be to get this working as expected with the built in [CookieProvider](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.state.CookieProvider) and then switch over to [Http Provider](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?24970-Buffering-Http-State-Provider).

Comment: That is a 2.x extension and when I tried to run it from 3.x, I got "undefined is not a function" trying to instantiate Ext.ux.HttpProvider(). Any advice on getting a 3.0 port?

Comment: IS it possible to store state of all the rows of grid?

Comment: @Shekhar - The grid state is concerned with the grid configuration. Not with the store data that you see in the rows. you will need to handle saving of rows at the backend and retrieve them using parameters to your server call from the store.

Answer (score 2):

The grid should have a property called "stateful".  Set this to True and the grid should remember the column widths, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the grid with `stateful: true` and set its `stateId` (optional if your grid has an ID that won't change). Also initialize the Ext.state.Manager:

```
var thirtyDays = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*30));
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({expires: thirtyDays}));
```

Though not included in Ext 3, you can find online a state provider that uses HTML5's `localStorage` rather than cookies.